# Facing 419 | Page Expired even if CSRF present in the form

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

- Laravel Version: 8.35.0
- PHP Version: 7.4.0
- Database Driver & Version:

#### Description:

Facing a CSRF issue when I deployed my project on a VPS server. Here is the video: https://www.loom.com/share/e2cd2c7ae2f6490ab1717d3243592513

Here is my form
[image: ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/43857625/113865389-d7d3bd80-97cd-11eb-83f5-db427a826598.png)]

I have no idea why I am facing this.

Here is my application:
https://tukhulu.com/login
https://tukhulu.com/register

Please help

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache (`php artisan cache:clear`) and that your vendor and storage folders have the correct permissions?

Comment: It might be a good idea to execute php artisan key:generate and generate a new app key which will, in turn, flush the session data.

Clear Browser Cache HARD, I found chrome and firefox being a culprit more than I can remember.


And try

add SESSION_DOMAIN=mydomain.com in your .env file

or in your config/session.php 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'mydomain.com'),

and then run php artisan cache:clear

Comment: @Pri Nce please reply did this help you...

Comment: @Unflux Yes I did, remains the same

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear all cache items

```
php artisan view:clear 
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

try changed the `session_driver`

if your project is running on server
add `SESSION_DOMAIN=yourdomain.com` in your .env file
or in your config/session.php `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'yourdomain.com'),`
then run

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

maybe switch between `'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),`
and `'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),` in your config/session.php